# Why i have weird code in my xml activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have an activity and its xml file contains weird code that i dont know what it is, before i never modified this file and i started the app on my phone without problem , but when i click to see this file it appears weird code then my app when i start , it gives me error always.

I have tried uninstall the android studio, clean project, rebuild but it did not work.

and as you see the code tags are without closing tags but i did not do that before and i am the only one who is creating de app.

and i tried to close all tags that are not closed but it did not work yet.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project version="4">
   <component name="AndroidLayouts">
      <shared>
      <config />
      </shared>
     </component>
    <component name="AndroidLogFilters">
    <option name="TOOL_WINDOW_LOG_LEVEL" value="debug" />
    <option name="TOOL_WINDOW_CONFIGURED_FILTER" value="Show only selected 
   application" />
  </component>
 <component name="ChangeListManager">
<list default="true" id="a8584d6a-7864-4893-be6c-50fd82a53f53" 
 name="Default Changelist" comment="" />
   <option name="EXCLUDED_CONVERTED_TO_IGNORED" value="true" />
   <option name="SHOW_DIALOG" value="false"
```

this is the error according to anroid studio:

```
Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\David\AndroidStudioProjects\GestiondeAsistencia\app\src\main\
res\layout\activity_visitar_al_cliente.xml:15: error: unclosed token.
C:\Users\David\AndroidStudioProjects\GestiondeAsistencia\app\src\main\
res\layout\activity_visitar_al_cliente.xml: error: file failed to 
compile.
```

Comment: you likely need to invalidate the Android Studio caches

Comment: how can i do that? thanks

Comment: try using search engine. Google for example. It is way faster than waiting me to reply

Comment: Try invalidating Cache
Menu File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score -1):

```
<option name="SHOW_DIALOG" value="false"
```

This is missing a closing bracket. Also, you're missing a closing to the list, component, and project.

XML works so that parameters are enclosed in opening and closing brackets either by self-closing it with `/>` or with body closing it with `</parameter>`. For example:

```
<option foo="hello" bar="world" />
```

Alernatively...

```
<foo>
   <bar value ="hello world!"/>
</foo>
```

Comment: that's not the problem. The problem is that whole part of that code should not be in the layout file

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Exactly the problem is why all those code are in the xml of a layout file why?